# Geometry nodes instance on points: objects populate OFF my object

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, origin

Scene has 2 meshes: a plane and a cylinder.  I have modified the plane to look like a simple terrain, so it has some surface variation.

The cylinder was translated from the origin and scaled, then I applied all transforms to it.

Then I created geometry nodes for the terrain and used instance on points to place the cylinder onto the terrain mesh.

Many of my instances are beyond the terrain mesh as you can see from the attachment.

[image: instance on points screen cap]

I would like to know if this is normal because my instance geo is not at the origin, or if there is some way to correct this so the instance geometry stays on the terrain..?

OP edit: the objective is to populate the cylinder over the plane surface, and it appears the reason for the mismatch is because the cylinder geo is transformed (with all transforms applied), but the object origin was not set to the object, causing an offset for the instances.  Thanks to Chris for pointing that out.

I would be happy to upload the .blend file but I don't see a way to do that.  (thanks to John E. for the blend-exchange tip).

Thanks!

Comment: You can share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to add the file link to your question.

Comment: just set the instance geo origin to geometry - solved. Why did you move the origin? maybe some details would help to understand what you want to do...?

Comment: Do you still want this re-opened? An object's origin **is** its location. (There's no rule saying that an object's mesh should be centred on its location.. that would be painful  ..  :) ) , so this behaviour is absolutely expected. Given that..  can you clarify what question remains?